# How to consult existing prolog file into C++ and it's module?

Tags: c++, swi-prolog

hi every body i have simple prolog file which calculate factorial, I want to know how to consult factorial.pl file and call it's module which named fact through C++.

here is my sample code but it doesn't work correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <SWI-Prolog.h>
#include <SWI-Stream.h>
#include <SWI-cpp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PL_initialise(argc, argv);

    predicate_t p_consult = PL_predicate("consult", 1, "database");
    term_t t = PL_new_term_refs(3);
    PL_put_string_chars(t, "D:\\factorial.pl");
    PL_put_integer(t + 1, 5);
    PL_put_variable(t + 2);
    qid_t query = PL_open_query(NULL, PL_Q_NORMAL, p_consult, t);
    int result = PL_next_solution(query);

    if (result)
    {
        int x;
        PL_get_integer(t + 2, &x);
        cout << "Found solution " << x << endl;
    }

    PL_close_query(query);

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

and factorial.pl

```
fact(N, F) :- N =< 1, F is 1.
fact(N, F) :- N > 1, fact(N - 1, F1), F is F1 * N.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I put the answer here maybe some other people have same problem.

my mistake was in consulting as I guessed, I use PlCall instead of predicate to consulting the pl source file, by the way you should put pl source file to the same folder of cpp files are in.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <SWI-Prolog.h>
#include <SWI-Stream.h>
#include <SWI-cpp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;

    PL_initialise(argc, argv);

    PlCall("consult('factorial.pl')");

    term_t a, b, ans;
    functor_t func;

    a = PL_new_term_ref();
    PL_put_integer(a, n);
    b = PL_new_term_ref();
    ans = PL_new_term_ref();
    func = PL_new_functor(PL_new_atom("fact"), 2);
    PL_cons_functor(ans, func, a, b);

    int fact;

    if (PL_call(ans, NULL))
    {
        PL_get_integer(b, &fact);
        cout << "Result is: " << fact << endl;
    }

    cin.ignore(2);
    return 0;
}
```